# How to remove all non-alphanumeric except dot or comma between 2 digits

Tags: java, regex, string, expression, alpha

I've searched a long time, but unfortunately, regex are really not for me...

I just want to replace all the non-alphanumerics except dot or comma between 2 digits (or plus) by a space.

Example : 
*Welcome to RegExr v2.1 by gskinner.com, proudly hosted by Media Temple ! -98.7 3.141 .6180 9,000*

became

*Welcome to RegExr v2.1 by gskinner com  proudly hosted by Media Temple 98.7 3.141 6180 9,000*

I know that this can remove all non-alphanumerics : [^a-zA-Z0-9 ]
but I just want to add the exception for dot or comma between 2 numbers (I've test on http://regexr.com/)

Thanks for your help ! ;)

Comment: Add `\.,` to your range [Example](https://regex101.com/r/oRE7vL/1)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
str = str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9 .,]|(?<!\\d)[.,]|[.,](?!\\d)", "");
```

The regex matches

- everything you definitely don't want, or
- a dot/comma *not* preceded by a digit, or
- a dot/comma *not* followed by a digit

Answer (score 2):

```
[a-zA-Z ]|\d([\.,]\d)?
```

The above will select the text you desire to keep.

It selects either Alphabetic characters + spaces and digits with optionally embedded .'s and ,'s. '|' works as a boolean OR.

Comment: FYI you don't need to escape a dot within a character class